# Symfony 1.3: how to force as inline the choices generated by renderLabel()

Tags: forms, symfony1

this line:

```
<li><?php echo $form['genero']->renderLabel() ?></li>
```

is generating

```
<li>

<label for="usuario_genero">Genero</label>

<ul class="radio_list">

<li>   <!-- this li doesn't have any id-->

<input type="radio" checked="checked" id="usuario_genero_0" value="0"
name="usuario[genero]">&nbsp;<label for="usuario_genero_0">Chico</label>

</li>

<li>  <!-- this li doesn't have any id-->

<input type="radio" id="usuario_genero_1" value="1"
name="usuario[genero]">&nbsp;<label for="usuario_genero_1">Chica</label>

</li>

</ul>

</li>
```

I'd like to force the choices as inline, but the li's generated don't have the 'id' attribute.

What should i do?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
ul.radio_list li
{
  display: inline;
}
```

Alternatively, you can create your own formatter for your radio widgets, or extend from the existing sfWidgetFormSelectRadio class and override the formatter() method to display the radio icons in the format you require.